# Bacteria and natural log problem

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

You have been tasked with growing a colony of bacteria starting with $5$ bacteria. Suppose the colony of bacteria is grow exponentially and can be modeled using the following function.

$$B(t) = \frac{30}{1 + 5e^{0.2t}}$$

How long will it take for you to triple (get $3$ times) the initial population of the colony using natural log?

I think I should use the logarithmic function of
$$y = \log_b x$$
but I am unsure of how to change the exponential equation into natural log.

Comment: Set the left side to $15$, manipulate to isolate the term with the exponent, _then_ use the natural logarithm.

Comment: I isolated the exponent and I got 0.2t = log5e(450). I think I missed a step...

Comment: The formula for $B(t)$ does not make sense.  As $t$ increases, $B(t)$ decreases, which suggests that the formula should be $B(t) = \dfrac{30}{1 + 5e^{-0.2t}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems that you missed something. As the comment of [Ethan Bolker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72858/ethan-bolke) says, the left side is $15$.

$$15=\frac{30}{1+5\cdot e^{-0.2\cdot t}}$$

First step is dividing the equation by 15.

$$1=\frac{2}{1+5\cdot e^{-0.2\cdot t}}$$

Multiplying the equation by the denominator of the rght side.

$$1+5\cdot e^{-0.2\cdot t}=2 \qquad |-1$$

$$5\cdot e^{-0.2\cdot t}=1 $$

Dividing the equation by $5$ and then taking logs (natural logarithm). The notation is $\log()$ or $\ln()$.

$$\ln \left( e^{-0.2\cdot t}\right)=\ln(0.2) \qquad $$

$$-0.2\cdot t=\ln(0.2) \qquad $$

Now we can use that $\ln(a)=-\ln\left(\frac1a\right)$

$$-0.2\cdot t=-\ln(5) \qquad $$

I leave the rest for you.