# Bacteria and logarithms problem.

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, biology

> You are taking a biology class and you are growing a colony of
> bacteria starting with 5 bacteria. Suppose the colony of bacteria is grow exponentially and
> can be modeled using the following function:

$$B(t) = \frac{30}{{1+5}e^{-0.2t}}$$

> How long will it take for you to triple (get 3 times) the initial population of the colony using natural log in the answer.

*Process:*

Since it asks for natural log, I know it needs the logarithm function.

I first added the 5 bacteria with the 3 to get 15 for `t`.

I then tried to isolate the exponent by itself:

$$B(15) = \frac{30}{{1+5e^{-0.2t}}}$$

$$B(450) = 5e^{-0.2t}$$

I then used the log function to get

$$0.2t = \ln^{-0.2t}$$

I know my answer is wrong. Any help please?

Comment: Did you mean this? $$B(t) = \dfrac{30}{1+5e^{-0.2t}}$$

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387160/bacteria-and-natural-log-problem

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please edit your question.  If you want to write $e^{-0.2t}$, type `$e^{-0.2t}$`.  I would try to edit your question myself, but I have no idea what you meant to write in the last formula.

Comment: It looks like you multiplied $15$ and $30$ instead of dividing them and made other algebraic mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The left side of your first equation should be $15$, not $B(15)$ as it is the number of bacteria you are interested in.  That is just notation.  When you did the algebra you skipped steps, so I cannot tell what is wrong.
$$15= \frac{30}{{1+5e^{-0.2t}}}\\
1+5e^{-0.2t}=2\\
5e^{-0.2t}=1\\
e^{-0.2t}=\frac 15\\
-0.2t=\log(\frac 15)\\
t=-5\log(\frac 15)$$

Comment: @cheeseg The implied base of the logarithm here is $e$.